# Certain characters not being read fom file - Python

Tags: python, file-io

I currently have a text file that looks like this:

[image: Text file]

But when I try to read it with:

```
file = open(filename, "r")
file = file.read()
```

It only reads "sc" out of the file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a binary file.
So Try open that file using binary mode.

```
with open(filename,"rb") as fh:
    fh.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `file = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', "r")`